# Oracle: how do I see what query was ran by a Java EE6 application?

Tags: java, oracle, jboss

I am building a small app for Jboss EAP 6.3 using Oracle 11g.

I implemented form based login as instructed by [this tutorial](https://dont-panic.eu/blogs/2012/sep/form-based-authentication-against-custom-database-jboss-7) but it doesn't work. 
It always fails, no matter the input.
I created two users:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM USERS;

        ID USERNAME             PASSWORD
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 admin                admin
         2 guest                guest
```

There are no errors in jboss console (or maven console when deploying).
But imputing either fails. 
"Invalid login or password" every time.
I want to know what exactly happens when I input the credentials. Does the database even get any queries from the app?

Ideally I would like to see a history of queries on db.

Found this error on server startup:

```
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.server.controll
er.management.security_realm.employee-rooster.properties_authentication: org.jbo
ss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.secu
rity_realm.employee-rooster.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to loa
d properties
```

Comment: In application server itself we would be having option to set the log level.  For WS I do know, JBoss, I am not sure.  As per the tutorial, hashed passwords were stored.  So while you input password, it will get converted to hash I guess, hence its failing

Comment: @user3694267 I set logging level to "DEBUG" but there are still no errors when I submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the logging configuration in the standalone XML file you are using:

```
   <logger category="org.jboss.security">  
     <level name="TRACE" />  
   </logger>  
   <logger category="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security">  
     <level name="TRACE" />  
   </logger>  
   <logger category="org.apache.catalina">  
     <level name="TRACE" />  
   </logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you followed that tutorial closely then you will need to store hashed passwords in your database rather than the plain text that is shown by your select statement above.

To quote the tutorial:

```
echo -n "admin" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64
echo -n "guest" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64
```

and update the password column in your db with the results.

Comment: I thought that because I didn't enable any hashing it didn't hash passwords. Also check my question, there is an update.